# rocketmq send a async message ,connect to nameserver failed

Tags: rocketmq

when i try to send a async message by rocketMQ,exception :
org.apache.rocketmq.remoting.exception.RemotingConnectException: connect to [192.168.2.115:9876] failed
pom:

```java
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.rocketmq</groupId>
                <artifactId>rocketmq-client</artifactId>
                <version>4.9.3</version>
            </dependency>
```

code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // 实例化消费生产者
        DefaultMQProducer producer = new DefaultMQProducer("async_group");
        // 指定NameServer地址，可以是多个，分号隔开
        // producer.setNamesrvAddr("localhost:9876;localhost:9877");
        producer.setNamesrvAddr("192.168.2.115:9876");
        // 启动producer
        producer.start();
        // 创建消息对象，指定主题topic，Tag和消息体
        Message message = new Message("async_basic", "async_tag", ("i am async body,num:").getBytes());
        producer.send(message, new SendCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult sendResult) {
                System.out.println("发送状态：" + sendResult);
            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Throwable throwable) {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        // 关闭
        producer.shutdown();

    }
```

i think it is the SendCallback,because sync message has no problem,and this code si right

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // 实例化消费生产者
        DefaultMQProducer producer = new DefaultMQProducer("async_group");
        // 指定NameServer地址，可以是多个，分号隔开
        // producer.setNamesrvAddr("localhost:9876;localhost:9877");
        producer.setNamesrvAddr("192.168.2.115:9876");
        // 启动producer
        producer.start();
        // 关闭
        producer.shutdown();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // 实例化消费生产者
        DefaultMQProducer producer = new DefaultMQProducer("async_group");
        // 指定NameServer地址，可以是多个，分号隔开
        // producer.setNamesrvAddr("localhost:9876;localhost:9877");
        producer.setNamesrvAddr("192.168.2.115:9876");
        // 启动producer
        producer.start();
        // 创建消息对象，指定主题topic，Tag和消息体
        Message message = new Message("async_basic", "async_tag", ("i am async body,num:").getBytes());
        producer.send(message, new SendCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult sendResult) {
                System.out.println("发送状态：" + sendResult);
            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Throwable throwable) {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Thread.sleep(100000);
        // 关闭
        producer.shutdown();

    }
```